# VS 2015 Xamarin can't see VS Android Emulator

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015, android-emulator

I had both the VS2015 community edition VS Android Emulator on my PC. After uninstalling both the old VS2015 community edition and VS Android Emulator and then installed the latest VS2015 community with Xamarin, then generated a Xamarin form for Android.  But there was no VS Android Emulator to be selected within VS.  I can manually run VS Android Emulator so I know it runs fine.  Strangely after a new install, all the old settings of both VS2015 and VS Android Emulator are still intact.  Any reason why VS2015 can't see, let alone invoke the VS Android Emulator?  I have repeated this uninstall and re-install cycle a few times and nothing changed.